# How do I prove that this function is monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

Let $f(x)=x/(1+|x-1|)$. How do I prove (without derivatives) that this function is monotone?

Based on the graph of this function, it is increasing so I figured to use the definition of an increasing function: if $x<y$, then $f(x)<f(y)$.

The piecewise definition for this function would be
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x/(2-x) & \text{if } x<1\\
1 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly $f$ is monotone when $x\geq 1$. But how do I prove its monotonicity for other values of $x$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider,

\begin{align}
f(y)-f(x)=\frac{y}{2-y}-\frac{x}{2-x}&=\frac{y(2-x)}{(2-y)(2-x)}-\frac{x(2-y)}{(2-x)(2-y)}=\frac{2y-yx-2x+yx}{(2-x)(2-y)}\\
&=\frac{2y-2x}{(2-x)(2-y)}=\frac{2(y-x)}{(2-x)(2-y)}
\end{align}

Now if $y>x$ , $x<1$ and $y <1$, clearly both the denominator and numerator are positive so $f(x)-f(y)>0.$

Answer (score 2):

It's straightforward to show, as you have done, that $f$ has the piecewise representation $\displaystyle f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x}{2-x},&x<1\\1,&x\ge1\end{cases}$. The $x<1$ component can be shown to be strictly increasing, since, if $x<x'< 1$ are two arguments, then we have
$$\begin{align}
f(x')-f(x)&=\frac{x'}{2-x'}-\frac{x}{2-x}
\\&=\frac{2}{\left(2-x'\right)\left(2-x\right)}\cdot\left(x'-x\right)>0
\end{align}$$

where the expression in the last line is a product of strictly positive terms. Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing over $(-\infty,1)$ and by extension, monotone on that interval. As $f$ is constant over $(1,\infty)$, it is trivially monotone there also. As $f(1)=1$ at the boundary between the two pieces, this proves that $f$ is monotone.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)=\frac{1}{2/x-1}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $2/x-1$ is monotonically decreasing on $\left(-\infty,0\right)$, $f$ is negative and monotonically increasing on $\left(-\infty,0\right)$. Similar argument applies to the segment $\left(0,1\right)$ on which $f$ is positive and monotonically increasing. Since $f(0)=0$, combining these arguments and consequently $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about derivatives, then you can easily observe that

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{2}{(2-x)^2}$$

which is always positive. Also here $x < 1$ guarantees that there are no problems at the denominator.

Since $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$, you can conclude it's monotone (increasing).

Comment: From the question: "without derivatives"